# Want to make a Chia farm of 156 external hard drives

Tags: voltage, amperage, ac-dc

I have two questions:

1. How do I not burn down my house
2. Is there any way I can use less electrical outlets by getting AC/DC splitters?

Question 1:

So basically I got 156 external hard drives. The AC adapter included with a single drive outputs 12V, 3.0A.

I'd like to make sure I don't burn down the house, so here's my math so far:

156 * 3.0A = 468.0A

12V * 468.0A = 5616W

Each breaker can do 15A * 120V or 1800W, right?

So 5616W/1800W = 3.12, so I'd need to use a minimum of 4 separate breakers if I used the AC adapters that came with the drives, right? So I could divide the 156 drives by 4 and do 39 drives per breaker and be perfectly fine, right?

Question 2:

I found some 1 female to 8 male DC splitters. If I wanted to utilize those, I would need a 12V, 24A (8x3.0A) AC/DC power supply, right? Does anyone have any recommendations on how or where to find a 12V, 24A AC/DC adapter? If I found one that does slightly less or slightly more would it work? How would I know?

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to look at the **input** current of the AC adapters.  The **output** is 3A, but the **input** will be much lower.  You have to add up the input current to find out how much current will be drawn from the outlet.

Comment: You're going to be damaging the planet with increased carbon dioxide emissions from the electricity generation and increased demand for drives, so it would be better to get some more efficient power supplies - instead of using one per drive, get PSUs which are capable of powering perhaps ten drives each.

Comment: I would use custom power sdistribution wiring rather than relying on those ready-made 8-way splitters.  The input connector on the splitter may not be rated for the total current you will be drawing from the eight outputs.

Comment: If any possible look at the data sheet of your drives. The average power consumption (which determines how much heat you need to manage) is going to be way less than 36W. Ideally you have a power supply that can deliver maybe 10W per drive long term and has higher peak current capability (for short periods of time)

Comment: Look at the BackBlaze open source hard disk arrays for some ideas around power and cooling.

Comment: You’re going to burn through a lot of external ac adapters as they are in my experience the most unreliable part of (consumer) external drive solutions. I would look into consolidating your drives into third party external enclosures with redundant power supplies. The money you spend on that will probably be offset by the increased efficiency and reliability. BTW what are you going to connect the drives to?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct.  In reality it’s likely that the drives will draw rather less than the 36W each, but it’s wise to allow for the maximum.  Check the current rating for your whole house - 5.6kW is a significant amount.  You’ll also need to consider how to get rid of the waste heat, don’t just stack up dozens of drives.  As you say, you’d need to use multiple AC outlets, and it’s up to you how you want to fan those out and where to do the AC-DC conversion.  It is certainly possible to get 12V supplies with significant power capability; perhaps check out PC power supplies, or those intended for amateur radio.  Don’t under-estimate the size of cables you’ll need to carry 20-40A with acceptable losses.

Answer (score 1):

Seagate’s Barracuda power spec is 12W seeking constantly and 3A or 36W surge startup on the 12V supply mainly.  This design must have sequenced power to avoid the all at once surge.  Thus a 1.5kW supply can power half of the drives easily if you invoke sequenced power on. This means only two 15A breakers required and the equivalent of 2 hair driers running. Exhaust air should be ported outside in a large plenum to reduce heat load inside. Air conditioned space is mandatory with conditioned power as well to filter transient loads on dry contact switches with 15A line filters in addition to the internal PSU filter. This also improves lightning noise immunity.

Cooling for reliability means the air gap between drives must have a 2ft/s air flow with a case temp <40’C. This requires a proper plenum design, not simply a box with case fans. It is not CFM that counts, rather LFS linear feet (or meters) per second over the metal surface.

Their 0.73% AFR rate means you can expect at least 1 unit failure per year with 156 drives and a lot more if you neglect the cooling temp limit.

Burning your house down is only a consequence of faulty wiring. The disk farm needs careful cooling air and ensure adjacent drives do not accumulated heat is ducted out with manifolds. less than 2kW max is not a major issue unless you have no ACU in the summer.

https://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/NL35%20Series%20&%20BC%20ES%20Series/Barracuda%20ES.2%20Series/100468393f.pdf

Comment: Any questions??

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can use less electrical outlets by getting AC/DC splitters?

remove the hard drives from their external enclosures and mount them directly in a storage server. Quite likely, replace them with better drives.

Having 156 external drives is also a recipe for all kinds of undesirable probabilities. Unless you're in the business of *testing* external hard drive enclosures, I don't think there's a single problem I'd solve that way, *especially* if these are consumer hard drives.

Think about this: for your system to be fully functional, you'd want **all** 156 drives to work. Assuming the (temporary) failure probability of an external hard drive is (in my experience very generously estimated) \$P_f = 1‰\$, the probabilty that it would work is \$P_W = 1-P_f\$; the probability that all 156 work is \$P_W^{156}\$, meaning that with probability \$P_{problem}=1-P_W^{156}\$ you've got a failure. In numbers, \$P_{problem}=1-P_W^{156}=1-(1-P_f)^{156}= 14.5\%\$.

> Each breaker can do 15A * 120V or 1800W, right?

Depends on your breaker. Also note that your 3A are *peak* current. You'd very much make sure you're not powering them all on at once. Also, since a single USB bus can only address 127 devices, and I assume these are not external Serial-attached SCSI platters, this will never actually be a problem.

> AC/DC splitters

never heard of such a thing? Do you mean "DC power supply (supplied by AC)"? In that, case, yes, having better power supplies will reduce your failure rate immensely. Again, I'm almost certain that there's very few problems you're solving with 156 external drives, and a lot of problems you're creating.

Comment: I mean 1 female to 8 male DC splitters connect to an AC/DC power adapter that outputs 12V and 24A.

Would there be an issue running them all at once even at peak amperage (3.0A)? The calculations I made to see if an outlet can take it were based on peak current anyways (12V, 3.0A), so even at peak current it should be able to take it based on the calculations. That's what I'm asking.

The devices would be connected to 4 RockPi's at 39 drives per RockPi, so 127 devices limit would not be met. This question isn't about USB device limitations. It's about electricity.

Comment: 3A is the max each power supply can provide, I would hope that the adapter is sized so that the hard drives are pulling substantially less than that, except for maybe short bursts.  You also have to take into account the efficiency of the converter, usually 80-90%.  Using fewer high-current AC-DC converters is probably the easiest way to go, and prevents you from having to daisy-chain outlet strips, which is where you are mostly likely to burn your house down.

Comment: Regarding removing the drives from their enclosures to use them in a server: it used to be that inside a USB enclosure was a standard desktop drive with a SATA connection and a USB->SATA converter board, but that is no longer guaranteed. Many (most?) external drives are designed for use in the enclosure with USB logic onboard the drive itself and are lacking the SATA interface or could have the SATA interface but need a modification to the connection itself.

Comment: Marcus, if all those 156 drives have to work then their MTBF is a "series" type MTBF for the system. Their rates add up (as in like \$\sum\$). See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures#Calculation). There's also [AFR](https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/hard-disk-drive-reliability-and-mtbf-afr-174791en/) discussed by Seagate. And don't forget the bathtub failure curve shape!

Comment: @Nolan what you describe is a case for a storage cluster of devices with error-corrected RAM and clever data redundancy schemes. Jonk is 100% on point – don't listen to me, check the manufacturer infos. You'll want to look up software for larger storage solutions, like Ceph. A wise lady said "the difference between a storage cluster and a bunch of servers with disks is that the storage cluster fails prettily", and that's really the point I was trying to make: with 156 drives, you're very much requiring your system to be failsafe, and choosing to go with external drives on cheap ARM boards...

Comment: ... you're pretty much stress-testing your luck, and in all honesty, the utility of 4 RockPis with nearly 40 drives attached to a relatively slow bus not intended for professional storage grade data integrity is to be doubted, even in the case that none of the *drives* fail – Please do try to figure out the bit error rates of your drives, the bit error rates of the RAM, and the USB connections. Compare that with the number of bits you're storing. I bet this is about some "clever" (very strong quotation marks on that) cryptocurrence scheme; you don't get *any* money for corrupt data.